# How do I turn off disasters in SimCity?

Tags: simcity-2013

I don't mind if my city has disasters such as fire because my city has fire stations nearby. But I have no way to handle other disasters and these disasters happen too often. Is there any way to disable disasters? It would be great if I could disable specific disasters instead of all of them.

**Update**

The disasters happen much less often now. An earthquake happens once after I updated to 1.3 and 18 hours of gameplay in cheetah speed in contrast to 2 hours in 1.0.

Comment: Isn't cheetah speed still disabled?

Comment: Yes, currently cheetah speed is the same as llama speed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only way you can disable disasters if you are playing in Sandbox Mode. Sandbox Mode is dependent on the region. The person creating the region has the option to make it Sandbox Mode.

**This allows:**

- All Buildings
- Limited Cheats
- No Random Disasters

**Note: Sandbox cities are ineligible for achievements, challenges, or leaderboards.**

Here is a picture showing you how you can do it.

[image: A picture of a emu]

Comment: It sucks, if so, but at least I don’t get attached to certain buildings the way I did in SimCity 4. Here I don’t care if anything burns.

Comment: I would like to add that I've heard developers talking about releasing a patch which allows us to disable disasters, so we shall see.

Answer (score 2):

The regions Cape Trinity and Sunrunner Bay don't have Tornados or Earthquakes (source: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AjxiNeaKIskndFRybzhWaEJfeUw5RW1ySjZoMlh5emc&single=true&gid=0)

There's no way to avoid the other disasters, besides turning on Sandbox Mode for the region.